# "I have already [seen]" vs "I already [saw]"

Tags: colloquialisms, present-perfect, simple-past

> I have already (past participle)
>
> I already (simple past)

I feel like when I'm reading literature or any serious writing, the present perfect is always used with "already". I would guess that this use is preferred, and I always make the effort to use it over the alternative.

However, I often hear the simple past used with "already" in conversation, as in "I already saw the movie." What is the status of this usage? Is it "acceptable", colloquial-only, really bad? It sounds really grating to my ears, but I'd like to make sure.

Answer (score -3):

It is correct to use "already" in both of your examples. While not considered colloquial to emphasize the past simple with "already," [it is uniquely American](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/already) to do so when the past simple occurs *before* something else happens.

For example, it would be uniquely American to write "I already saw the movie before I had gone to bed." The Brits would say only "I saw the movie before I had already gone to bed."

Comment: *"I have already seen that movie"* does ***not*** necessarily mean you watched it many times on separate occasions. It never has meant this. This is incorrect.

Comment: Your first sentence is true. I re-read my postscript and deleted it, realizing that it was not written well. Thank you for pointing that out. However, your second sentence is false. Here’s a clear example: simply saying "I have already seen that movie" when you have already seen a movie six times. I think you started off fine, but you let your emotions derail you.

Comment: And another thing: while the web page you link to says that you should not use the past simple with already, one of the examples they give actually does: "*We already knew that he was coming to visit."* So things are actually more complicated than the simple proscription they give. (This is because *"know"* is a stative verb.)

Comment: No, you simply don't understand. They say they don't use already with past simple only for something completed before something else happened. With that said, using it in the sentence you quoted is perfectly okay. But I can tell you're trying, and that's commendable.

Comment: Speaking as an American who sometimes uses the simple past with 
*"already"*, I don't believe *"I already saw the movie before I had gone to bed"* is a sentence in which Americans would use the simple past.

Comment: In order to write about two things happening at different points in the past, you use past simple with one occurrence and present perfect with the other. That is standard practice in America.

Comment: Not like that, though. I ***might*** say *"I had already seen the movie before I went to bed"* (although the past perfect and the *"already"* both seem unnecessary here), but not the other way around as you suggest.

Comment: Apparently you take issue with my citation. Write someone a letter, just not me. I don't work for them.